Hibernate custom projection migration from 3 to 5 throws a HibernateException: Unable to locate mapping for function named <custom_func>
I have an older code on Hibernate 3
public static final class MyCustomProjection extends AggregateProjection
  {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public CustomFuncProjection(String field)
    {
      super("custom_func", field);
    }

    @Override
    public String toSqlString(Criteria criteria, int loc, CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery) throws HibernateException
    {

and when the Criteria is built it's just added to the ProjectionList:
projections.add(new MyCustomProjection(tableAlias + field.name()), fieldAlias);
It was working just fine in Hibernate 3 but after I built with 5 it throws
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Unable to locate mapping for function named <custom_func>
during the execution. What am I missing?
I have tried to build with Hibernate 5 jars and did a lot of adjustments in other areas for it but expected projections to work.
